# perception_pcl compile issue

Tags: ros, perception-pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm trying to compile perception_pcl on my Pi 2. I have compiled pcl 1.7 and that's installed sucessfully. But I'm getting the error messages below - all saying the file pcl_msgs/PointIndices.h cannot be found. This is apart of the pcl distro and the file is on the system. Any ideas?

Thanks

Mark

```
Building CXX object perception_pcl/pcl_ros/CMakeFiles/convert_pointcloud_to_image.dir/tools/convert_pointcloud_to_image.cpp.o
Building CXX object perception_pcl/pcl_ros/CMakeFiles/convert_pcd_to_image.dir/tools/convert_pcd_to_image.cpp.o
[ 29%] Building CXX object perception_pcl/pcl_ros/CMakeFiles/pcd_to_pointcloud.dir/tools/pcd_to_pointcloud.cpp.o
[ 30%] Building CXX object perception_pcl/pcl_ros/CMakeFiles/pointcloud_to_pcd.dir/tools/pointcloud_to_pcd.cpp.o
In file included from /home/pi/ros_ws/src/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/tools/pcd_to_pointcloud.cpp:51:0:
/home/pi/ros_ws/src/pcl_conversions/include/pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h:59:35: fatal error: pcl_msgs/PointIndices.h: No such file or directory
#include <pcl_msgs/PointIndices.h>
^
In file included from /home/pi/ros_ws/src/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/tools/convert_pointcloud_to_image.cpp:49:0:
/home/pi/ros_ws/src/pcl_conversions/include/pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h:59:35: fatal error:     pcl_msgs/PointIndices.h: No such file or directory
#include <pcl_msgs/PointIndices.h>
^
In file included from /home/pi/ros_ws/src/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/tools/pointcloud_to_pcd.cpp:48:0:/home/pi/ros_ws/src/pcl_conversions/include/pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h:59:35: fatal error:   pcl_msgs/PointIndices.h:     No such file or directory
#include <pcl_msgs/PointIndices.h>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228805/perception_pcl-compile-issue/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2016-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay found the problem - the PCL build takes up over 2Gb of swap space (god knows why) when compiling some parts. So increasing the swap space did the job (Took over 24 hrs on Pi 2).

Also - should anyone else happen on these I kow the Pi 2 has 4 corse but set =-j1 because as stated the demand on memory is so high that is won't make any difference.

Mark

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2016-03-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0